# Sketch $|x|^{1000}+|y|^{1000}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Here is the graph:

[image]

which has rounded corners when you look closely:

[image]

How do I sketch this?

My thoughts are as $-1 \le x,y \le 1$

if $-1 < x < 1$

$x^{1000} \approx 0$

$\therefore |y|^{1000} \approx 1$

By symmetry, the reverse argument applies for $y$.

This gives the "square" shape with the seemingly straight "sides".

The corners are rounded as we are dealing with a continuous graph so if $|y|$  decreases slightly, then |x| increases slightly to compensate

(reverse argument applies for $x$)

This graph is difficult to sketch without software so any further insights from the community on how to sketch this graph would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the question? It looks like you answered it already.

Comment: There's nothing "special" about the near square shape. Try graphing $y=x^{1000}$ and then $y=x^{1001}$. Basically, even with simple polynomials, you get seemingly sharp corners and "right angles" when you choose large exponents.

Comment: The corner point is $(0.999307,0.999307)$. Unless you are zoomed in, as your inset is, this graph will look imperceptibly different from a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about a special case of the $p$-norm, where the "unit circle" is defined by
$$
|x|^p + |y|^p = 1
$$
for various values of $p$. When $p=2$ it's a circle. As $p$ approaches infinity the circle looks more and more like a square, as you note.

[image]

(From wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)

When $p$ is large it's hard to sketch since at any reasonable scale it looks like a square. You need software to zoom in.

To get a reasonable approximation for $p$ not too large you could use a calculator to solve
$$
2x^p = 1
$$
to find out where the "circle" meets the diagonal line $y=x$.  Then you could fill in with a freehand curve and be confident of reasonable accuracy.

It's fun to check this out for values of $p$ between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your reasoning is completely right since for $0<x<1$ we have that $|x|^{1000}\approx 0\implies |y|^{1000}\approx 1\,$ by symmetry the sketch is very closer to a square with side $L=2$.